# What could cause php value to be true and false?

Tags: php, debugging, boolean-logic

I have a class with this function:

```
public static function getSingleton($modelClass='', array $arguments=array())
{
    $registryKey = '_singleton/'.$modelClass;
    if (!isset(self::$_registry[$registryKey])) {
        if (isset(self::$_registry[$registryKey])) {
            throw new Exception('Mage registry key "'.$registryKey.'" already exists');
        }
        self::$_registry[$registryKey] = self::getModel($modelClass, $arguments);
    }
    return self::$_registry[$registryKey];
}
```

The exception is being thrown. HOW can the exception be thrown? I can't think of any way that isset() and !isset() could both return true - yet they are! How could this happen? I am using APC, could that have anything to do with it? How would I even debug this?

Comment: Don't think this is causing the issue but should `$key` be `$registryKey`?

Comment: Is self::$_registry defined? is it an array? Not that $key will be undefined because it isn't in scope

Comment: It may have something to do with `__isset` magic method on the class, or if `$registry` is an object that implements the `ArrayAccess` interface (or the `__isset` method on `$registry` too)

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós Can you rephrase that in the form of an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that the object has the [magic method](http://php.net/oop5.magic) `__isset()`, which may cause some weird behaviours if coded poorly.

Also, it is possible that `$registry` isn't a simple array but an object which implements the [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/arrayaccess) interface. Then you must look for the `__isset()` magic method if present, and the method [`OffsetExists`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/arrayaccess.offsetexists.php) more precisely.

Comment: I was not aware that isset could be overridden! My problem turned out to be that the method was being overloaded with isset replaced with a function that returned the value of the argument instead of true on success, which I would not have noticed if I hadn't been testing the arrayaccess and isset magic methods.

Answer (score 1):

Isset tests if the variable or index has been initialized or not and does not always use booleans. The value could just as well be null and the proper way of testing this (since PHP is loosely coupled) would be:

```
if (isset(self::$_registry[$key]) === true)
```

Or better yet;

```
if (array_key_exists($key, self::$_registry))
```

I always suggest using [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) instead of [isset](https://www.php.net/isset) since the first one is much more reliable for true/false conditions.

**Edit:** Also, like the comments stated - your variable is `$registryKey` and not `$key`.